# kubernetes. What is the maximum distance/latency supported between kubernetes nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a kubernetes cluster.

I want to have a single cluster with master, worker and proxy nodes in High Availability with nodes in both locations.

Is it documented the maximum distance or latency supported between locations?
Additionally I would appreciate links to official documentation, I couldn't find anything related.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no latency limitation between nodes in kubernetes cluster. They are configurable parameters.

For [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/) on worker node it is:

```
--node-status-update-frequency duration    Specifies how often kubelet posts node status to master. Note: be cautious when changing the constant, it must work with nodeMonitorGracePeriod in nodecontroller. (default 10s)
```

For [controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-controller-manager/) on master node they are:

```
  --node-monitor-grace-period duration    Amount of time which we allow running Node to be unresponsive before marking it unhealthy. Must be N times more than kubelet's nodeStatusUpdateFrequency, where N means number of retries allowed for kubelet to post node status. (default 40s)
  --node-monitor-period duration          The period for syncing NodeStatus in NodeController. (default 5s)
  --node-startup-grace-period duration    Amount of time which we allow starting Node to be unresponsive before marking it unhealthy. (default 1m0s)
```

Comment: Is this considered a good pattern or is this a hack? I was under the impression that the master nodes should all be in the same region if we're talking AWS and that the workers should all be in the same Region as the Masters.  I played in ~2016 with sprawling worker nodes across the globe and it worked except for timeouts, maybe this would allow that setup though? Nomad vs K8s for example claims "can be deployed across multiple availability zones, regions, and data centers"