# Is it possible to configure multiple master nodes to prefer routing to different nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-networkpolicy, kubernetes-networking

Imagine a scenario where I have 3 classes of worker node (A,B,C) and 2 master nodes (X,Y) as part of a Kubernetes cluster. There maybe multiple worker nodes of each class. Is it possible to route the traffic such that traffic arriving at the different master nodes is routed to a different set of worker nodes. For example I want master node X to route traffic to workers of class A and potentially fail over to class B under heavy load and for master node Y to route traffic to nodes of class C but also use B as a failover when needed.

Comment: First, "traffic" typically does not arrive to your master nodes. Your master nodes are only used for "control plane". Second, think about routing in terms of routing to your application, not to nodes. You can deploy applications to a certain group of nodes.

Comment: Thank you I've gone and re-read the part on traffic that had confused me into thinking traffic went via master and it makes more sense now. That being the case then how could I achieve the idea above. Say I had users in Japan and users in Germany. Maybe I pay a substantial sum to host some quality hardware in those two regions and want the people from those regions to be routed too near by nodes to avoid latency and then maybe have some far cheaper instance that would for the failover instance. Is there a way to avoid that without going with a multi cluster approach ?

Comment: A clusters should be installed in a single region. This is because a cluster contains a distributed etcd database that replicates data, you want it to have relatively short latency between it's nodes. All managed kubernetes solutions is per region.

Comment: So with a quick look over:
https://www.cloudping.co/grid/p_99/timeframe/1M ,
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891273/kubernetes-what-is-the-maximum-distance-latency-supported-between-kubernetes-no

the master/worker node latency shouldn't pose to much of an issue given that Kubernetes is working in an order of seconds whilst the cross region latency isn't really getting far over 1/3 of a second at it's worst. That being said the question is more of an "is it possible" instead of a "is it useful"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in the comments, the traffic is not handled by the master nodes; its responsibility, at a high level, is to observe and maintain the desired state of the Kubernetes resources deployed in the worker nodes, as well as to push any changes to them.

That being said, yes, it is possible to discriminate and send the traffic to different worker nodes using [Topology Aware Hints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/topology-aware-hints/):

> Topology Aware Hints enable topology aware routing by including
> suggestions for how clients should consume endpoints. This approach
> adds metadata to enable consumers of EndpointSlice and / or Endpoints
> objects, so that traffic to those network endpoints can be routed
> closer to where it originated.

This feature is specifically designed to handle traffic in a multi-zone environment and has a series of built-in [Safeguards](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/topology-aware-hints/#safeguards) to prevent situations like overload of an endpoint, insufficient endpoints in a zone, etc.